# Google Maps - User Drives By Marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

While I know you can add custom markers into a map. Is there an event that fires when a user passes through that custom marker? Say there are 30 custom markers on a map and a user has to collect them all kind of like in Pokemon Go or Waze (candy collection appears on the map), is something like that possible? Note this is for an android app. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic, I've been searching for a bit but haven't found something like this or maybe I don't know the correct terminology.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Daniel!